# XML format to import content in Wordpress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I need to create a XML with the content of an old site to import in Wordpress with oficial [Wordpress Importer Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/).
Based on [XML exported by Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen), I can create a compatible export export of my content. This export is like this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" ...>
<!-- xml header based on Wordpress export -->

<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
    <item>
        <title><?php echo $post['title']; ?></title>            
        <pubDate><?php echo date('r', strtotime($post['date'])); ?></pubDate>
        <dc:creator>admin</dc:creator>          
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<?php echo $post['content']; ?>]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[<?php echo $post['excerpt']; ?>]]></excerpt:encoded>          
        <wp:post_date><?php echo $post['date']; ?></wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt><?php echo $post['date']; ?></wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>           
        <wp:status>publish</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
        <category><![CDATA[<?php echo $post['category']; ?>]]></category>
        <category domain="category" nicename="<?php echo StringToSlug::gen($post['category']); ?>"><![CDATA[<?php echo $post['category']; ?>]]></category>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>

    </item>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Wordpress imports this well. Now I want to add a thumbnail to each post. I only find examples with the id of the image post ID, like these example:

```
<wp:postmeta>
    <wp:meta_key>_thumbnail_id</wp:meta_key>
    <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[43]]></wp:meta_value>
</wp:postmeta>
```

Of course this do not work for me, because the content does not belong to another Wordpress site.
How can I handle that? Is there any other way to import post thumbnail? Or there is another way to import posts for another non-Wordpress (nor non-Blogger/Drupal/Joomla) content?

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have the following in your post's import code:

```
<wp:postmeta>
    <wp:meta_key>_thumbnail_id</wp:meta_key>
    <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[43]]></wp:meta_value>
</wp:postmeta>
```

that usually means that this record of type post is referencing another record of type attachment, so lets say you have a post with id# **5** you need to add another item somewhere with `<wp:post_type>attachment</wp:post_type>` and a `<wp:post_parent>5</wp:post_parent>` like this:

```
<item>
    <title>imagefile1</title>
    <link>http://www.mysite.org/yourpostpermalink/attachment/imagefile1/</link>
    <pubDate>Fri, 06 Dec 2013 10:24:03 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator>you</dc:creator>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/imagefile1.png</guid>
    <description></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[]]></content:encoded>
    <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
    <wp:post_id>43</wp:post_id>
    <wp:post_date>2013-12-06 11:24:03</wp:post_date>
    <wp:post_date_gmt>2013-12-06 11:24:03</wp:post_date_gmt>
    <wp:comment_status>closed</wp:comment_status>
    <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
    <wp:post_name>imagefile1</wp:post_name>
    <wp:status>inherit</wp:status>
    <wp:post_parent>5</wp:post_parent>
    <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
    <wp:post_type>attachment</wp:post_type>
    <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
    <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
    <wp:attachment_url>https://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/imagefile1.png</wp:attachment_url>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_wp_attached_file</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[imagefile1.png]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>

</item>
```

i hope this helps

Comment: This is interesting. I'll try it soon! Thanks!

Comment: Also you need to order your import items attachments top and posts after, this way the thumbnail image will exist in the new Wordpress db and it will be able to reference it while importing the post.